# Why first element of array is empty?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a function which returns an Observable and once its fires I'm looping the subscribed array

```
this.productService.getProductBySeo(proudctName).pipe(
        catchError(e => of(null)),
        this.unsubsribeOnDestroy
      ).subscribe(res => {
        if (res) {
          this.categoriesService.currentCategory.subscribe(menus => {
            const activeElem = res;
            const allItems = menus;
            allItems.map(item => {
              console.log(item)
              console.log(item.id) // can see id of each elem 
              console.log(item.children) // first element of item.children is empty
              ....
```

[image]
[image]

**UPD 1**
I have changed to switchMap as it was advised in comments , anyway the arrays is empty

```
  this.productService.getProductBySeo(proudctName).pipe(
        catchError(e => of(null)),
        switchMap(res => {
          this.categoriesService.currentCategory.subscribe(menus => {
            if (menus) {
              const activeElem = res;
              const allItems = menus;
              allItems.map(item => {
                console.log(item)
                // console.log(item.id) // can see id , 
                console.log(item.children) // still empty :-(
                item.children.map(item => {
                  // console.log(item);
                  return item
                })
                const fountObj = item.children.find(el => {
                  // console.log('element ', el)
                  return el === activeElem;
                });
                if (fountObj) {
                  this.totalStyle = item.seo_url; // to identify total style of the component
                }
              })
            }
            // console.log(menus)
          })
          return of(res)
        }),
        this.unsubsribeOnDestroy
      ).subscribe(res => {
        if (res) {

          this.product = res;
```

Regarding what do I expect to see is when subscription fires in `this.categoriesService.currentCategory.subscribe`, I want to see `item.children` in console. As I see only empty array when log `item.children` , but when I console just `item`, I can see that `item.children` has 2 items in own Array

Comment: How does the original data look like ? Also please mention what is the expected results versus what's the actual results and your current thoughts on the problem

Comment: A side note, you should look into `switchMap` instead of nested subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great solution, But I suspect that it might have been changed by reference on somewhere else. Try deep cloning and looping.
i.e.

```
const allItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(menus));
allItems.forEach(item => {
   console.log(item)
   console.log(item.children)
```

Also, forEach looks much better than a map in such circumstances.